# Datatables Export to Excel hangs on IE11 (>10k records)

Tags: datatables

Im using datatables for displaying data on the webpage. Have also added and Export button which would export the data in Excel format.
 There are around 10k records that would be displayed /filtered. The export to excel doesnt work when tried from IE11 however the same works from Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.13).

Can you advise if this is a known issue and is there any fix for it.

```
var table = $('.tableContent').DataTable({    
    "autoWidth": false,    
    "pageLength": 50,    
    dom : 'lBfrtip',    
    buttons : [ {    
        extend : 'excel',    
        text : 'Export to Excel',    
        exportOptions : {   
            modifier : {    
                // DataTables core    
                order : 'index',  // 'current', 'applied', 'index',  'original'    
                page : 'all',      // 'all',     'current'    
                search : 'none'     // 'none',    'applied', 'removed'    
            }    
        }    
    } ],

    "columnDefs" : [{    
        "targets" : [ 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11,  17, 18 ],    
        "visible" : true,    
        "searchable" : true    
    }, {    
        "targets" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21 ],    
        "visible" : false,    
        "searchable" : false    
    }]    
});
```

Comment: Are you able to profile the operation from within chrome developer tools?

Comment: Can you tell me how to profile the operation?

Comment: Use the developer tools > profile > profile cpu